# Reading XLS file in Java using POI is getting Error

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I want to convert a `xls` file into `xlsx` file but at the time of reading XLS , its getting error.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    xlsTOxlsx xls=new xlsTOxlsx(); 
    InputStream isXls = new FileInputStream("/xyz/MUM_FIN_DATA_BI_1jul16.XLS");
    HSSFWorkbook workbookOld = new HSSFWorkbook(isXls);
    String dest="/media/ram/Project/Apollo/MUMFINDATABI1jul16.XLSX";
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dest);
    XSSFWorkbook workbookNew = new XSSFWorkbook();
    xls.transformHSSF( workbookOld , workbookNew) ;    
    workbookNew.write(out);
    out.close();
}
```

I am getting following error at 
HSSFWorkbook workbookOld = new HSSFWorkbook(isXls) :

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Invalid header
>   signature; read 0x0A0D3E6C6D74683C, expected 0xE11AB1A1E011CFD0

After doing google I found these points:

1. Its not a original file of XLS.
2. Open the file and save as XLS, Its working fine.

But how can I do by java code??

Comment: Can you try with a newer version of Apache POI, eg 3.15 beta 2? That gives more helpful error messages for common non-XLS file formats

Comment: After Using  Apache POI 3.15 beta 2 its getting almost same issue:
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.NotOLE2FileException: Invalid header signature; read 0x0A0D3E6C6D74683C, expected 0xE11AB1A1E011CFD0 - Your file appears not to be a valid OLE2 document

Comment: If you open it in Excel and do a Save-As, what does Excel suggest the current format is?

Comment: At the time of Save_As its suggest current format is: Web Page

Comment: A ha! So, that explains why POI can't read it - it isn't an Excel `.xls` file, it's just a HTML table in the preferred Excel format. You'll need to use a HTML parser to process it

Comment: ok,thanks Gagravarr

Comment: so what is the solution ?